# How to reset Gnome 3 contacts?

Tags: gnome

I've switched to Gnome 3 recently, and now trying to figure out how the contacts app/integration works. I had some issues in the beginning with my google account and now it mixed a "local adress book" (another application had the brilliant idea to import my google contacts and store them as local) with a google adressbook. Now i am left with a lot of duplicates and mixed contacts.

I wanted to reset the contacts, and start fresh, but can't figure out how i would do that.

I did try restarting the initial setup, by disabling dconf "org > gnome > contacts > did-initial-setup" - which triggered it, but that did not reset my contacts either. It made it even worse, after that i now have 3 accounts listed in it, the same google account twice and a local adressbook.

Disabling and even completely removing my google account from the Online-Accounts settings and keychain does not seem to affect it.

Can anyone tell me where these things are stored? How can i wipe the contacts from the system and start fresh?

In case it matters, this is Gnome shell 3.8.4 (Ubuntu Gnome 13.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, realized that it's using evolutions addressbook and not a separate contacts database. Renamed the

> ~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook

to

> ~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook-old

and restarted gnome to test, and it was fresh again (now only one google account (that is linked in Online Accounts) is used for the contacts).